# how can I download Package PDF for java

Tags: java, pdf, package

```
public void createPDF( String path ) {  
    // Met deze functie  wordt er een PDF aangemaakt van de huidige factuur  

    try {  
        Document document = new Document();  
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path + ".pdf"));  
        document.open();  
        document.add(new Paragraph("Factuurid = " + Integer.toString(this.id)));  
        document.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  
}///this shows errors
```

Comment: this will show errors if you do not have the required JAR. it looks to me like you are missing the iText library, and your question is not very clear

Answer (score 2):

you can download iText, a PDF creation library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/). you will need to decompress the file and inside there will be various JARs.

You will need to reference itextpdf-5.2.1.jar in your projects settings as an external JAR. Of course, the version number may vary.

In Eclipse Indigo, you can do that going to Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add external JARs.

more information about iText on their  [Website](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php).